Why can't I list files in FTP?
I would like to transfer files between a phone (HarmonyOS 2.0.0) and a Linux laptop. I run a FTP server (without username and password) using ES File Explorer on the phone, by following some replies at How do I transfer files between Android and Linux over USB?. Then on the Linux laptop, I run the client, but why can't I list the files? I have given ES File Explorer permission to access the storage of the phone.
$ ftp 192.168.200.100 3721
Connected to 192.168.200.100.
220 ESFtpServer 0.1 ready.
Name (192.168.200.100:t): t
331 User name okay, need password.
Password: 
230 User logged in, proceed.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Active Mode.
425 Cannot open data connection.

